# iPhone: How to get the currency symbol from an amount string?

Tags: objective-c, ios

I have a list of amounts in different currencies(e.g. $10.99, 20.55€). I would like to find out the currency symbol of each string in order to parse the amount.

Do you have any ideas ?

Regards.

Comment: Where are these strings coming from?

Comment: How is it generated? (Downloaded from server, etc.)

Comment: It's an export from a poker tracking software

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use regular expressions to find the first symbol that is not a digit or a decimal separator:

```
NSError *error = NULL;
NSRegularExpression *symbol= [NSRegularExpression
    regularExpressionWithPattern:@"[^0-9.,]"
    options:NSRegularExpressionCaseInsensitive
    error:&error];
NSRange r = [symbol
    rangeOfFirstMatchInString:myString
    options:0
    range:NSMakeRange(0, [myString length])];
if (!NSEqualRanges(r, NSMakeRange(NSNotFound, 0))) {
    NSLog(@"Currency symbol is '%@'", [myString substringWithRange:r]);
}
```